# Empty tax_query array returns an empty array

Tags: wp-query, query, terms, tax-query

I would like to return all posts when the tax_query['terms'] is empty.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__not_in' => $exclude,
        's' => $filter,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => array(),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Unfortunately I didn't find solution for the problem. As you can see the array is empty: `'terms'    => array(),`but I would like to return all posts. How can I achive that?

Comment: Check if the array is empty before adding the tax query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already hinted by @Milo, check if you have terms before appending your `tax_query`

You can try the following: (*Requires PHP 5.4+ due to short array syntax, revert to old syntax if necessary*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => $exclude,
    's' => $filter,
];

// Append our tax-query if we have terms. Make sure it is a valid string or array
$term = 'DEFINE YOUR TERM HERE';
if ( $terms ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
            'terms' => $terms,
        ]
    ];
}

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Perfect, it works :)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)